# MySQL: how to sort rows by a field and assign another field a counter?

Tags: mysql

Imagine there's a table with the following contents:

```
 x      y     z
 aa     5     null
 bb     2     null
 cc     5     null
 dd     1     null
```

I want to sort the rows by `y` and assign an auto-incremented field to z, so in this case the end result (the changed table) would be

```
 x      y     z
 dd     1     1
 bb     2     2
 aa     5     3
 cc     5     4
```

or

```
 x      y     z
 aa     5     3
 bb     2     2
 cc     5     4
 dd     1     1
```

How do I do that?

So to make it clear, I want to change the table, not get that stuff to code.

As requested, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd610/1

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: [you can fiddle with user variables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d054/2), but usually this kind of thing is more easily & reliably left to application code.

Comment: @JohnConde, added to body

Comment: where are all the answers gone?! there were at least 2

Comment: None was correct. The posters deleted them by themself. Do you want a select or an update query?

Comment: @juergen d, I want to update the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update your_table t1
inner join
(
  select id, @rank := @rank + 1 as r
  from your_table, (select @rank := 0) r
  order by y
) t2 on t2.y = t.y
set z = r
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b6f2/1)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I might call the "painful" solution.  It uses a subquery to calculate the rank for each row:

```
update t
    set z = (select count(*) as cnt
             from (select t.* from t) t2
              where t2.y < t.y or t2.y = t.y and t2.x <= t.x
            )
```

Note that MySQL generates an error when you use the target table in a subquery in `update` and `delete`.  There is a way around this.  Just embed the table in a subquery.

You can also do this using a variable with a `join`:

```
update t join
       (select t.*, (@rank := @rank + 1) as seqnum
        from t cross join (select @rank := 0) const
        order by y
       ) t2
       on t.x = t2.x
set t.z = t2.seqnum;
```

The subquery calculates the sequence number with the `order by`.  The outer `update` then assigns the value to the appropriate row.  This assumes that `x` uniquely identifies each row.